# SLURM: Wait for job within job script

Tags: slurm

I have a SLURM job script `a` which internally issues an `sbatch` call to a second job script `b`. Thus, the job `a` starts job `b`.
Now I also have an `srun` command in job `a` which depends on the successful execution of `b`. So I did

```
srun -d afterok:$jobid <command>
```

The issue is that dependencies are seemingly not honoured for job steps which I have in this case because my `srun` runs within the job allocation `a` (see the `--dependency` section of https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html).

The question: I really need to wait for job `b` to finish before I issue the job step. How can I do this without resorting to separate jobs?

Comment: Have you tried submitting the second job with a dependency? I.e.: srun -d=afterok:<jobidA> . With afterok you are saying that job B will only start if job A finishes correctly.

Comment: I did this. Won't work on the srun command when it is executed from within a job script. I think I'll just have to create a job of its own and submit it with sbatch -d afterok:<jobidA>. Thanks for your comment!